# Django 2.2 | Auto-reload doesn't detect changes in new apps

Tags: python, django

Just created a new project with Django CLI.
My project split into multiple apps so the structure is like this:

```
project
app1/
    ..
    migrations/
    views/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    urls.py
core/
    ..
    migrations/
    views/
    __init__.py
    apps.py
    urls.py
project/
    settings/
        __init__.py
        common.py
        development.py
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

I'm using Docker to build the environment and make sure that both apps registered in the `INSTALLED_APPS` property.

The problem is that the Django doesn't listen to `app1` app, but only to `core` app. Also, if I add another folder under the `core` app, it's doesn't listen to this folder as well.

I've changed the `BASE_DIR` property to support the new structure:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have your `app1` in settings `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes, even created another app through the CLI, and it doesn't help.

Comment: Run `echo 'from django.conf import settings;print(settings.BASE_DIR, "\n", settings.INSTALLED_APPS)' | ./manage.py shell` to show your settings.